# glossaries package and footnote in LaTeX

Tags: latex, footnotes, glossaries

I am currently stuck, having two separate glossaries: `main` & `acronyms`. `Acronyms` glossary prints footnotes on first use in the text, but `main` glossary does not. Is there any way to make any other glossary than `acronyms` to print footnote on first use of the term? I don't get how to do it.

Here is the code example compiled with TeXnic Center and MiKTeX 2.7:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage[toc,style=long3colheaderborder,footnote,acronym]{glossaries} 

\makeindex 
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{appdomain}{name={application domain}, description={app Domain Description...}}
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={[has been inserted aaa]},description={testing testing 123}}

\newacronym{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}
\section{this is a test section}
This is the test line... a \gls{sample} \gls{appdomain} 
\index{entry} and \gls{aca}
\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage

\printglossary[type=main,title={Glossary},toctitle={Glossary}]
\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations},toctitle={List of Abbreviations}]

\printindex
\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

I want sample and appdomain either contain a footnote with description or a footnote stating: please refer to Glossary

Many thanks,
Ovanes

Comment: can you post a snippet that will illustrate your problem?

Comment: Are you using the standard `\glossary` command or a package like http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=glossaries?

Comment: I am using the \glossaries package, which is the further development of \glossary. I will try to make a snippet, but I am not sure if it is really required, since when importing the package as: \usepackage[toc,style=long3colheaderborder,footnote,acronym]{glossaries} declares the acronyms to be in a separate glossary. After acronym appears first time in the text I get a footnote, but if the normal glossary phrase appears I don't see it. Doc states that \acronym is smth. like a forward declaration to the \newglossaryentry. How can I make normal glossary entry appear first time with footnote?

Comment: You can find a whole community of TeX users at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, with the `glossaries` package, you can't get footnotes on the first use for non-acronym glossaries.

However, you can redefine some commands in the preamble (after you `\usepackage{glossaries}`) to get what you want:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\gls@main@displayfirst}[4]{
  #1#4\protect\footnote{#2}
}
\makeatother
```

But that will be really fragile.

Comment: Wow! That is exactly, what I was looking for. Why is it fragile?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I did not get immediately. I now got it what means `fragile'. If I change glossary name or type, it will break. But anyway thanks!

Comment: Exactly! Perhaps this should be filed as a feature request with the maintainer of the package…

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easier way of doing this. Maybe it's new, but

```
\defglsdisplayfirst[main]{#1#4\protect\footnote{#2}}
```

appears to achieve the exact same thing (correct me if I'm wrong). See the `glossaries` manual, version 2.03, subsection 2.4.1 *changing the format of the text*.

Unfortunately, it appears commands like `\gls` or `\autoref` does not work in those footnotes.

Comment: This method is deprecated, [says the documentation](http://ctan.sciserv.eu/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), page 112, in the footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a good technique, to put a footnote stating where the definitions are:

```
\label{nom} %put this on the page your term appears, so that it can collect page number

\newcommand{\g}{\footnote{For all abbreviations see the glossary on page \pageref{nom}.}}
```

I've found this from [here](http://openwetware.org/wiki/LaTeX_template_for_PhD_thesis).