# Example for a simple LaTeX glossary

Tags: latex, glossary

I'm trying to include a simple glossary to my LaTeX document,

I already searched for something like that on google, but never got it running.

I would like to use glossary or glossaries.

1. how to write it in the text?
2. how to print it?
3. what to execute on which position?

Comment: a kind of index, a subject index on things like WWW -> World Wide Web..

Comment: On editing, I see that you may already have found my suggestion. It would help if you said *what* you tried, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: I agree completely, is there no simple step by step example. I have read the documentation including the beginners.pdf, and I can only see the Table of Contents entry in my file, but it points to my very first page, and does not create a glossary page at all, anywhere in the document..

Comment: see my answer and the links in it.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there is a [`glossaries` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/) on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/). Read the [pdf documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf).

Check if you already have it in your installation, if not install it, and put `\usepackage{glossaries}` in the preamble of you document and it will be available to you.

---

It looks like you need `\usepackage{glossaries}` and `\makeglossaries` in the preamble, and some number of `\newglossaryentry` and `\newacronym` calls (it is not immediately clear to me if these only go in the premble or can go in the document text). Finally, you will need one or more `\printglossary` calls in the text. Use `\gsl` to connect glossary entries on the argument with the pages they occur on.

Processing the file will have to include a call to `makeglossaries` followed by at least one more invokation of latex.

In addition to the samples mentioned in the documentation there is [a Stack Overflow question which includes a minimal file making use of `glossaries`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633016/glossaries-package-and-footnote-in-latex) You may be particularly interested in the acronym glossary.

Comment: The `glossary` package is *deprecated*! Use `glossaries` instead.

Comment: *"The glossary package is deprecated!"* Which would be why my latex distribution doesn't have it. I do wish the README or the documentation would say as much. Updating the answer...

Comment: in fact I only know that it’s deprecated because when I opened the docs using `texdoc glossary` on my LaTeX installation, that’s what it said (I have TeX Live 2009 installed).

Comment: already found the documentation.. read it undestand nothing.
is there no simple step by step example for using glossaries?

Comment: I know I am very late, but I found [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) guide to be pretty helpful.

Comment: If it would work it would be helpfull yes...

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice blog for beginners: [LaTeX glossary and list of acronyms](http://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/)

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load the package
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Generate the glossary
**\makeglossaries**

\begin{document}

%Term definitions
\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{name=ADT, description={Atlantic Daylight Time}}
\newglossaryentry{est}{name=EST, description={Eastern Standard Time}}

% Use the terms
\gls{utc} is 3 hours behind \gls{adt} and 10 hours ahead of \gls{est}.

%Print the glossary
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice Blog recommendation.

Comment: After removing the compilation error `**\makeglossaries**` to `\makeglossaries`, it still does not compile: **``Package glossaries Error: Glossary type `acronym' has not been defined.``** [Errors when using glossaries package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152851/errors-when-using-glossaries-package). You have to change `\usepackage{glossaries}` to `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`. See the question [\printnoidxglossaries vs \printglossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426010/printnoidxglossaries-vs-printglossaries) for a complete usage tutorial about latex glossaries.